# Deploying to a server and remote debugging with FlashDevelop?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder, flashdevelop

Is there any way to automatically deploy to a server after I build a flex app, and then debug using the remote url ?

This is totally possible in FlashBuilder, but I am highly hoping that it can be done in FD as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can script any action you want in a batch file and then go to Project->Properties->Build->Post-build-command and enter your batch file execution line.

To jump to a debug URL after compiling, just go into  Project->Properties->Output, select "Open document" and type your URL.

Comment: I save the FLA project into a new XFL project that comes with Flash CS5.  The "open document" via url stops working. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a debug version of your SWF, you can start FlashDevelop debugger for remote debugging (see Debug menu) and then navigate to the online page where your SWF resides.