# How to configure FlashDevelop to debug in web browser?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm following directions to [set up a debugging in FlashDevelop in web browser](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3%3aDebugging#Debugging_in_a_web_browser).  I'm getting confused on 'Configure your project' step. It says:

> Open the Project properties and change the "Test Movie" option to
>   "Open Document...". Click on the  button which should appear,
>   and enter *bin/index.html* (path to html page, relative to project root)
>   in the prompt.

What is the `bin/index.html` file? Is it where my SWF is loaded?  I currently have a SWF that loads from a PHP page. So I pointed it to my PHP project's index.php page build project.  After build I get a generic Windows message that Windows cannot open the file with that extension.

Is it possible for me to debug my SWF from my PHP page which loads it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience directly with what you're talking about, but I guess you have to point to a PHP file which is running in a webserver. Otherwise it can't be interpreted and run.

If you are running locally, you can use xampp, put your things in htdocs, and use localhost url to reference the file: http://localhost/projectname/index.php

Comment: Yeah, it's incomplete labeling and documentation on part of FlashDevelop. I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5650304/37759

Comment: For local tests you just can put your project in htdocs, then you don't have to deploy. Or (better solution) you edit the apache config file to link a certain URL to the bin directory of your project, no matter where it's stored in your computer.

Comment: I point to https://localhost/index.php and select Run in FlashDevelop, it builds and opens that URL fine. However, when I try to log in to my site it throws an exception. I've tried putting a breakpoint before the line where it throws the error but it never hit that breakpoint.

Comment: what's the error? And you say "select Run" that doesn't sound like you are debugging. Breakpoints only work in debug

Comment: Error is specific to my application. At one point I'm trying to retrieve a property of an object which is null. I know how to fix it, the more important thing is to get the debugging to work. When I select Run the dropdown next to it is set to Debug http://screencast.com/t/F8cBoQAlMMs0

Comment: Hm, well, here I come to the point "I don't have experience directly with what you are talking about". But maybe this helps: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3:Debugging